# Spring : Default html error page is not properly displayed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I want to redirect my web site to a default error page when there is a error like 404 , 406 and etc. I have followed an example and wrote following methods in the controller.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
private static final String PATH = "/error-page";

        public String getErrorPath() {
            return PATH;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value=PATH, produces="text/plain")
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> handleGet(HttpServletRequest request) {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("status", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"));
            map.put("reason", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"));

            return map;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value=PATH, produces="text/plain")
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> handlePost(HttpServletRequest request) {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("status", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"));
            map.put("reason", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"));

            return map;
        }
}
```

There is a html page as error-page.html in the above mentioned path. Although I got no errors, I cant display this error page while getting an error. Instead usual error message is shown. What is the issue here?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code snipped is missing the class declaration -> Does this controller implements the Spring ErrorController?

Comment: No in home controller

Comment: Then try changing `public class HomeController {` to `public class HomeController implements ErrorController {`.

Comment: Where do you catch your error ? In which portion of your code fetched errors? Normally If you want to show error page on request, then you should use `ModelAndView` to specify your view (page) and data. `@ResponseBody` didn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if with "...usual error message is shown" you mean the White-label error page. But if you want to deactivate this and show your own error-page you have to put in your application.properties or yml:

`server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`

And then add an `ErrorController` like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

  private static final String PATH = "/error";

  public MyErrorController() {}

  @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
  public ModelAndView handleAllException() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("error_template");
    return modelAndView;
  }

  @Override
  public String getErrorPath () {
    System.out.println("-- Error Page GET --");
    return "error";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to redirect to other controller
for example `return "redirect:/controllerPath"`.
  After that in that particular controller you should write the code to load the require jsp page.

```
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
public String loadErrorPage(){
 return "errorPage";
}
```

In your Case I dont see any method for catching error how ever you have this method

```
 public String getErrorPath() {
            return PATH;
        }
```

if this method is getting called at some point after error do it like this

```
 public String getErrorPath() {
            return "redirect:"+PATH;
        }
```

hope this helps.